# iTextSharp IndexOutOfRange Exception when Add a Barcode like the Documentation

Tags: itext, barcode, indexoutofboundsexception

i rewrote the Example of iText (Java) 
http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=297
in iTextSharp (C#) like this..

```
var document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document,
                                                 new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write,
                                                                FileShare.None));
        document.Open();
        var cb = writer.DirectContent;
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Barcode EAN.UCC-13"));
        var codeEan = new BarcodeEAN {Code = "230482304"};
        document.Add(new Paragraph("default:"));
        document.Add(codeEan.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.WHITE));
        codeEan.GuardBars = false;
        document.Add(new Paragraph("without guard bars:"));
        Image i = codeEan.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
        document.Add(i);
        codeEan.Baseline = -1f;
        codeEan.GuardBars = true;
        document.Add(new Paragraph("text above:"));
        document.Add(codeEan.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null));
        codeEan.Baseline = codeEan.Size;
        document.Close();
```

but getting following Exception

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

       at iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodeEAN.GetBarsEAN13(String _code)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodeEAN.PlaceBarcode(PdfContentByte cb, BaseColor barColor, BaseColor textColor)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.Barcode.CreateTemplateWithBarcode(PdfContentByte cb, BaseColor barColor, BaseColor textColor)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.Barcode.CreateImageWithBarcode(PdfContentByte cb, BaseColor barColor, BaseColor textColor)
```

Where is my mistake? Its 1:1 the Example on there Page... i dont found something for C#, but a C# Port and no Doku is a little bit... nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're providing an invalid EAN barcode value to your `BarcodeEAN`'s `Code` property.  EAN barcode values must have a specific format including a minimum character requirement and with the last digit being a checksum.  You can find more about this format [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_%28EAN%29).

There are plenty of resources available for validating EAN barcode values.  Over at codeproject.com there's [an article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10146/An-EAN13-Code-Control) with C# code that will validate an EAN13 barcode and will also calculate the checksum digit for a given 12 digit EAN13 barcode value.